# Firebase Functions: is it possible to prevent default logs "Function execution started" and "Function execution took..."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

In short: Is it possible to prevent default debug logs:
`Function execution started` and `Function execution took {time} ms, finished with status code: {code}` in Firebase Functions?

By default it seems GCP logs (https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) logs every start and finish of function execution. If I would like to log only my own log from a certain function would it be possible to prevent this default logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can control/remove the default logs, they are logged by the function wrapper solution that executes your function. They should case performance degradation to your implementation. if what you looking for is to not see them in cloud logging you can use log exclusion

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions